# Text out of Wordpress Page

Tags: css, wordpress, overflow

I need to create a website in Worpress but I have some problem with the text adaption to the page. The text is running out of the page border in some desktops and I don't know how to fix it. I've tried changing the template but I don't know where I'm wrong. I also tried to use some CSS codes trying to solve the problem but they didn't work. I'd like to adapt the content of my pages to the screen. I have also a vertical menu, so it gets more difficult I think. I tried this codes:

```
  div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  text-overflow: scroll;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.overflow {
    width: 10em;
  outline: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
  
  /**
   * Required properties to achieve text-overflow
   */
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Please help me. The website is: https://tarotstheseries.altervista.org/

Comment: Hi Anna, I tested your website but couldn't replicate the problem. Can you share a screenshot or specify at what browser window width the problem occurs?

Comment: Same here, can't reproduce the problem, seems like you might have fixed it, voting to close.

Comment: Actually, the problem occurs not for all screen size, but just for a certain dimension (before the screen is smaller and it's almost "mobile device"). https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/2623/Ecbqlo.png

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I pasted text using [ctrl] + V into a blog post or page, it would cause a text overflow problem. However, if I typed in the text or used [ctrl] + [shift] + V, the problem stopped.